# Capping storage usage in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any safeguard for capping your own **storage size** on BigQuery?
Or a way to be alerted if a certain size threshold is reached?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to cap the size or to alert when a size is reached. You can, however see how much is used in the api console .... go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and click on BigQuery and it will show your usage.